# Is it necessary to use decay width calculated at the same order as the scattering process?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering

I would like to calculate higher order corrections to a process for which there is an intermediate resonance which subsequently decays into lighter states. I am confused about how to treat the width of the resonance. Is it correct to say that in order to preserve unitarity, the order at which the decay width of the resonance is calculated should match the order of the process I'd like to calculate? So an LO cross section requires LO decay width, etc.

Comment: Ooh, that is a good question. I'm not sure you can exactly preserve unitarity in perturbation theory at all, but I'll leave it to someone more experienced in that area to post an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the votes (?) and for the edit. I think the question is valid for a decay process as well. It is kind of obvious in the narrow width approximation, but I don't know if there is a general proof that includes finite width effects.